# Declaration of function pointers

Tags: c, pointers

1. To declare a function pointer using `typedef`, it will be something like:

   `typedef void (*FOO)(int i)`

   But normally the syntax for `typedef` is like:

   `typedef int BOOL`

   so why is the first one not:

   `typedef void (*)(int) FOO`
2. To return a function pointer (without `typedef`), the syntax is as follow:

   `void (*foo(char c))(int)`

   which means `foo` takes in a char and returns a pointer to a function which takes an int and returns nothing. The syntax is so weird! It looks like `foo` takes in an int and returns nothing. The parentheses don't seem to be in the right places. If it is to return a function pointer, why is it not something like:

   `(void (*)(int)) foo(char c)`

   which is very straightforward. I am really having trouble understanding the syntax here, let alone using it. Can someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: It just is what it is. What exactly is your question? You already seem to understand how all this works.

Comment: When you´re declaring an int, you write the name after `ìnt`. When declaring a function, the name is *between* return type and parameters. Same here, name not after the whole stuff, but in the middle. And the name is not `foo`, but `foo(...)`

Comment: I suppose `typedef char MyArray[10];` rather than `typedef char[10] MyArray;` also causes you discomfort?

Comment: Some delcarations (like func ptrs and array typedefs/array pointer parameters) have to be read "from inside out". Your observation that this slightly differs from the other kind of typedefs is valid. In my opinion noone likes this syntax, modern languages also ditched similar syntaxes (see delegate/array delcarations for example in C#). In my opinion in case of func/array ptrs always use a typedef. If you return a funcptr from a function or you pass funcptr as parameter then declare the return value and/or function parameter with the typedef of the other funcptr to write readable code.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I've been doing C++ for 10 years and yes, that always irks me.

Comment: This has always seemed backwards to me too, and I will periodically still have to look it up... I find it slightly strange the response that you are getting here.

Comment: @MooingDuck It did me as well for a long time. been at it over 25 years now, and I think I grew numb to it at about year 13, so you have that to look forward to =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaration syntax is based on the types of *expressions*, not objects.  Another way of saying it is that "declaration mimics use".

Let's start with a simple pointer expression; call it `iptr`.  `iptr` points to an integer value.  If we want to access that value, we need to *dereference* `iptr` with the unary `*` operator, like so:

```
x = *iptr;
```

The *expression* `*iptr` has type `int`, so the declaration of `iptr` is written

```
int *iptr;
```

If you wanted to create a typedef for an `int` pointer, you would add the `typedef` to get

```
typedef int *iptr;
```

`iptr` now serves as a synonym for type "pointer to `int`", so you can write

```
iptr ip;
```

which declares `ip` as a pointer to `int` (as a rule, you really don't want to hide pointers in typedefs).

Now let's say you have a pointer to a function that takes two `int` arguments and returns an `int` value, call it `fp`.  To call the function, you dereference the pointer and pass the necessary arguments to the resulting function, like so:

```
x = (*fp)(arg1, arg2);  // C allows you to omit the * in the call, so you could
                        // also write it as simply x = fp(arg1, arg2), but we're
                        // leaving it in so the following explanation makes sense
```

The function call `()` operator has higher precedence than unary `*`; `*fp()` will be interpreted as `*(fp())`, which is not what we want.  To dereference `fp` before calling the function it points to, we must explcitly group the `*` operator with `fp`.

The type of the *expression* `(*fp)(arg1, arg2)` is `int`, so the declaration of `fp` becomes

```
int (*fp)(int arg1, int arg2);
```

Let's look at your second example now: `foo` is a function that takes a `char` argument and returns a pointer to a function that takes an `int` argument and returns `void`.  You'd call it as something like

```
(*foo(c))(x);
```

Again, the type of the *expression* `(*foo(c))(x)` is `void`, so it follows that the declaration is

```
void (*foo(char c))(int x);
```

For syntactic reasons, `typedef` is treated as a storage class specifier like `extern` or `static`, although it has a very different meaning.  It doesn't change the structure of a declaration; it just changes how that declaration is interpreted by the compiler.  Adding `typedef` to the above, as in

```
typedef void (*foo(char c))(int x);
```

now creates the synonym `foo` for the type "function returning pointer to function returning `void`".  It's no different from how simpler type definitions like

```
typedef int *iptr;
```

behave.

Answer (score 4):

An integer is just:

```
int x;
```

A name for the above is given by:

```
typedef int x_type;
```

A pointer to an `int` is:

```
int *p;
```

It's type would be:

```
typedef int *p_type;
```

A function called `foo` taking a ``` double``and returning an ```int` is:

```
int foo(double);
```

Defining the type of `foo` would be:

```
typedef int foo_type(double);
```

Now a pointer to the above should take an `*`, but `()` (function call) binds tighter than `*` (dereference), so parentesis:

```
typedef int (*ptr_to_foo_type)(double);
```

This might be better written:

```
typedef foo_type *ptr_to_foo_type;
```

as some suggest writing for clarity.

The idea is that the type description looks (somewhat) like its use. Badly mangled idea, given prefix/postfix operators, that much everybody agrees on. But it is now much too late to change.

Answer (score 0):

1) The syntax for typedef is to take a declaration of a variable of that type and put `typedef` in front of it.

2) The syntax for declarations echos the syntax for actually obtaining a value of that type. See my other recent answers regarding precedence of addressing operators (including function call), such as [(*twod)[3] vs *(twod)[3] C Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186060/twod3-vs-twod3-c-pointers/22186174#22186174) ... I'd rather not repeat it all again.